# how to display google map inside gridview android

Tags: android, google-maps, gridview, dictionary

I want to display multiple stores with store name,address,store location in **mapview in a gridview**.

My doubt is this possible to display maps in adapter for display **multiple mapview** in a single activity.

I initialized map in adapter but getting the error.

02-12 19:58:39.510: E/AndroidRuntime(21397): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #243: Duplicate id 0x7f05002a, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
02-12 19:58:39.510: E/AndroidRuntime(21397):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4248)

Answer (score 0):

1. Post your code as we'll not guess what your doing wrong.
2. You may want to use [Lite Mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite).
3. Yes it possible to have multiple maps.
4. [Check how you're adding the map fragment](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments).

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a fragment. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.